# Not able to allocate memory for vector

Tags: r

```
setwd("C:/Great Learning Sessions")
getwd()

mydata<-read.csv('Coffee1.csv')
brand_popular<-mydata[mydata$No_of_Packet,mydata$Brand]
brand_popular
```

Error I am Getting as follows: I am not able to allocate memory for vector `brand_popular`

```
brand_popular<-mydata[mydata$No_of_Packet,mydata$Brand]
```

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 512 Kb

Comment: Generally, this looks like you are out of memory.  Perhaps your CSV is too large.  How large is `Coffee1.csv`?

Comment: And do you have other things eating up memory?

Comment: The comma in this `mydata[mydata$No_of_Packet,mydata$Brand]` would indicate separation of rows and columns.  Try `mydata[, c("No_of_Packet","Brand")]`

Comment: coffee1.csv is  9.88 MB is that a problem

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on in this question, some of which I think can be confusing to R beginners, especially if you come into R from either a different kind of statistical package or a spreadsheet.  Also some of it will at first look inconsistent but eventually come to seem natural.

Part of this issue is that your problem with memory is masking another problem, which is how you are doing the subsetting.  Most likely fixing the subsetting problem will fix the memory problem.

Data frame subsetting in R can focus on row, columns, or both.  You can select whole columns or whole rows or either rows or columns based on boolean statements (that can be evaluated as TRUE or FALSE).   In your case, you want to select whole columns that have specific names. Therefore you only want to give the specific names.  There are two ways to do this that give the same result.

```
 identical(iris[c("Sepal.Length","Petal.Length")],
          iris[,c("Sepal.Length","Petal.Length")])
```

Notice the subtle difference between the two.  The first simply gives the names of the columns you want in a vector.  This is taking advantage of the fact that a data frame is also a list (of columns)  and you can subset lists using the names of the elements of the list, in this case the column names.  The second one takes advantage of the fact that a data frame works kind of like a matrix (one that can have different types of data, which makes it not a matrix in R).  Being matrix-like you can refer to parts of it via rows and columns, with rows, columns   separated by a comma.    That means if you want multiple rows or columns you need to provide them as a vector created with `c()`.

However it's important to note that the way you are referring to the columns (with the `$`) notation is not the correct way to do this.  That is actually referencing the whole column of data *as a vector* (or in the tidyverse as a tibble with one column).  In other words if `iris$Petal.Length` it's not just saying get me the column with this name, it's actually saying get me all the columns that have names that match the values in the Petal.Length column of iris.

In your original code this is made even more complicated because it says get me all the rows with row names that have the values in the "Brand" column which is going to cause all kinds of problems given that Brand probably does not contain unique values and row names should be unique.

For learning I encourage you to try all these variations (and more) with a small data set like iris so you can see the huge variety of possible error messages that can happen before you run out of memory.

Addition:

Just to add a bit more to this ... you may have used the `$` notation because you saw or used it before in the context of subsetting, but that would usually in the context of subsetting using a boolean statements.  For example

```
iris[iris$Sepal.Length  > 5,]
```

subsets those *rows* that have values of Sepal.Length greater than 5. It does this by creating a separate logical vector with the same number of rows as iris and in which the value is TRUE for those rows where Sepal.Length >5 and false for the other rows.  Then only those rows that match the TRUE rows in the other vector are retained.  This is equivalent.

```
  x <- iris$Sepal.Length  > 5
  iris[x,]
```

To use the same idea of a logical statement for columns you need a logical vector the same length as the vector of column name you want to keep.  So for example colnames() gives us the vector of column names and then 
      x<- c("Species", "Sepal.Length")
      colnames(iris) %in% x
gives us a logical vector

```
  [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

so

```
   iris[, colname(iris) %in% x]
```

would give us the data frame with just the two columns where the statement is true.  Which seems complicated until you want to make a function that accepts an arbitrary list of column names to subset.

Answer (score -2):

You can try setting a larger memory limit like

`memory.limit(size = 2500)`

where the number for the size is provided in megabytes.

Comment: Also use `attach(mydata)` to use your header as a variable. 
So that you can use  No_of_Packets and Brand as variables directly making it simpler.

Comment: than guys i will try and will let you know